# entityform association with organic group

Tags: 7, organic-groups, entities

Is it possible to associate entityform with organic group?
Ive created form and would like it to be accessible by a group specified.

Organic Groups allow to make that possible with content types but I was wondering if this is possible with entityform.

If not - are there any alternatives?

Comment: Anyone have any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you and I have two very similar questions going. This is a link to my question, which you (@sly) have a nice answer to, and which also includes my custom module answer: [Organic Groups access to Entityforms: is it possible?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69204).